# Rounding a number to lowest hundred using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am looking for a way to round any number to its lowest hundred. Example if the numeric value is 975, it should display as 900. If the values is 975.55, then also it should display 900. Can someone please tell me how can I achieve this using XSLT ?

Comment: What've you tried yet?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet as I could not find any relevant examples to try and test for. Is this something possible using XSLT? Do I need to use format-number function ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `floor($number div 100) * 100` then you should get what you want.

Comment: @SudhaRani: consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @SudhaRani: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.